# Which web analytics for Vue.js application and Nginx?

Tags: analytics, vue.js, nginx

We are building a Vue.js web application with Nginx on the backend and are in need of web analytics.

I've just started researching this and am not sure what to choose. I am aware of Google Analytics and have come across Matomo, OWA and Fathom Lite. Would any of those be good or something that analyses Nginx logs?

More specific requirements would be:

- Only a self-hosted analytics platform, not a cloud solution.
- It should allow submitting navigation events from HTML5 history push API.
- It should allow submitting custom events.
- It should gather data on a user’s device (OS, resolution, browser) and allow it to use it as a filter for events and page visits.